# Hibernate advanced select

Tags: java, hibernate

We want to get a row from a table using Hibernate a la:

1. `select max(id) from mytable where date = <date>`
2. Then `select * from mytable where id = <max_id>`

We are currently using Hibernate to map `mytable` to Java domain objects.

I know how to load the domain object based on an id.  So I could just do #1 using JDBC and then load the domain object using Hibernate the "normal" way.

But..  is there a way to do this with one single Hibernate logical query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [subqueries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries).

Comment: Looks promising..  would help if I RTFM.